# Neighbourhood of two distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a,b,c$ and $d$ such that the matrix $
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb C^{2,2}
$ has to two distinct eigenvalues. Give a neighbourhood $U\ne\mathbb C$ in which are both eigenvalues. How do one one handle this problem? I thought about Gerschgorin circles, but I am not sure. Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: A neighbourhood of *what*?

Comment: it is an old exam question. There is nothing else stated

Comment: I guess $U$ should just be an open set containing both eigenvalues. Note that the absolute value of any eigenvalue is smaller than the Frobenius norm. That is a pretty common inequality.

Comment: So probably it's a neighbourhood of each coefficient. Or a neighbourhood of the matrix for some matrix norm, but in this case it's a neighbourhood in $\mathbf C^{2,2}$.

Comment: After enlarging $U$, $U$ is a neighbourhood of anything you want. Basically the question asks you to bound the eigenvalues in terms of $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @MooS So let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ eigenvalues of A. wlog $\vert lambda_1 \vert > \vert lambda_2 \vert$. Then $\lambda_1 < \Vert A \Vert_F$? But what now?

Comment: This might be another interpretation, but then the formulation of the question is heavily flawed. But it is possible, since the set of matrices with distinct eigenvalues is of course open, even Zariski open.

Comment: Have you tried Gershgorin's theorem? You could find the Gershgorin disks and take their union, then the eigenvalues have to be in this closed set of $\Bbb C$. I don't know about a "neighbourhood" though; I suppose you could just take a neighbourhood around the origin which contains both Gershgorin disks.

Comment: @Dave that was my thought